# How to set foreign relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am very new in  Laravel.I am developing a website using laravel4 and this going to be a very basic question about the foreign key relationship in Laravel4.i am struggling with setting up foreign keys.My problem's explanation is given below.Please make a closure look here.

i am developing a website which has two basic portion.

```
1.Blood Donation
2.Matrimonial
```

my website's basic mapping is something like this.here it is

->First an user will signed up with basic information like name,email,password and password again

-> then user will sign in.**example** user signed in as a Robert Moore.

->after signed in as Robert Moore, user will get two link( 1.Blood Donation form 2. Matrimonial Form)

-> then it will users wish whether he/she will registered him/herself as blood donor or matrimonial or both.

now **after sign in**, if user(Robert Moore) choose the blood donation form or want to be a blood donor ,then i said before that, he/she will provide a form.namely **blood Donation Form**.here is the form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{URL::route('blood-donation-post')}}" method="post">          <div "form-group">
                     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Age" name='date_of_birth'{{(Input::old('age')) ? ' value="'.e(Input::old('age')).'"' : ''}}>
                       @if($errors->has('date_of_birth'))
                        <span style="color:red">{{$errors->first('date_of_birth')}}</span>
                       @endif
                    </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Blood Group</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name='blood_group'>
                        <option>You Must Select your Blood Group</option>
                          <option>O-</option>
                          <option>O+</option>
                          <option>A-</option>
                          <option>A+</option>
                          <option>B-</option>
                          <option>B+</option>
                          <option>AB-</option>
                          <option>AB+</option>
                      </select>
                        @if($errors->has('blood_group'))
                         <span style="color:red">{{$errors->first('blood_group')}}</span>
                        @endif
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Location</label>
                       <select class="form-control" name='location'>
                          <option> You Must Select a Location</option>
                          <option>MAGURA</option>
                          <option>MEHERPUR</option>
                          <option>NARAIL</option>
                          <option>SATKHIRA</option>
                          <option>BOGRA</option>
                          <option>CHAPAINABABGANJ</option>
                          <option>JOYPURHAT</option>
                          <option>PABNA</option>
                        </select>
                       @if($errors->has('location'))
                         <span style="color:red">{{$errors->first('location')}}</span>
                       @endif
                    </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Phone Number" name='phone_number'{{(Input::old('phone_number')) ? ' value="'.e(Input::old('phone_number')).'"' : ''}}>
                       @if($errors->has('phone_number'))
                        <span style="color:red">{{$errors->first('phone_number')}}</span>
                       @endif
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Date of Blood Donation</label>
                     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Last Date of Blood Donation" name='last_date_of_donation'{{(Input::old('last_date_of_donation')) ? ' value="'.e(Input::old('last_date_of_donation')).'"' : ''}}>
                     @if($errors->has('last_date_of_donation'))
                      <span style="color:red">{{$errors->first('last_date_of_donation')}}</span>
                     @endif
                  </div>
                  <div style="padding-left:20%">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Submit</button>
                    {{ Form::token() }}
                  </div>
</form>
```

Though the user Signed in as Robert Moore(as example),then if he want to be a blood donor,he will have to provide only the information associated with blood donation accept his name ,email because these information has already been stored in the **user** table when he make a sign up.Thats why i have provide  those fields in the **Blood Donation Form**(given above) which is associated with the blood donation **except name ,email**.Now these submitted data  will  store in the **donor** table.

Now,Here what i have done that, make an **one-to-one** relationship between **User** table and **donor** table through foreign key because the signed in user is the same user who actually the blood donor too.Now i will show you the migration file about the **Donor** model where i have made a foreign key relationship with the **User** model.here is the  migration file(partial),

```
 Schema::create('donors', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        //$table->increments('donor_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('donor_id');
        $table->foreign('donor_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('blood_group');
        $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
        $table->string('location');
        $table->date('date_of_birth');
        $table->date('last_date_of_donation');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

but after submitting the **Blood Donation Form**(given above),i am facing an exception something like that,

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`needa`.`donors`, CONSTRAINT `donors_donor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`donor_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `donors` (`date_of_birth`, `blood_group`, `location`, `phone_number`, `last_date_of_donation`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2014-08-13, A-, SHARIATPUR, 01796580404, 2014-08-13, 2014-08-17 05:30:38, 2014-08-17 05:30:38))

after lots of research and googling and make query in other forum,someone told me that,this is happening because, i don't specify the associated user or user hasn't been created yet,but i am already logged in as user(Robert Moore).so i am not convinced with that answer.So i need help from you guys.May be i have made a massive mistakes here but i couldn't figure it out since i am very new in Laravel.

for better convenience i am giving my both **User** and **Donor** model here too.

User Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function Donor(){
        return $this->hasOne('Donor','donor_id');
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

protected $fillable = array('email','username','password','password_temp','code','active');

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';



/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Donor Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

 class Donor extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    protected $fillable=array
    (   //'donor_name',
        //'email',
        'blood_group',
        'phone_number',
        'location',
        'date_of_birth',
        'last_date_of_donation'
    );

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code when saving the donor data:

```
$user = Auth::user(); // get logged in user

// create donor
$donor = Donor::create([
    'date_of_birth' => $date_of_birth,
    'blood_group' => $blood_group,
    'location' => $location,
    'phone_number' => $phone_number,
    'last_date_of_donation'=> $last_date_of_donation
]);

// save new donor and associate it with the user
$user->Donor()->save($donor);
```